# Lebesgue integral with gamma function

Tags: real-analysis

For $\alpha>1$, please show that $$\int\limits_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx=\Gamma(\alpha)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$
$\left(\text{by the way,}\,\,\,\, \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}\right)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1} \frac{e^{-x}}{1 - e^{-x}}\, dx &= \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{-nx}\, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-nx}\, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x}\, \frac{dx}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha} \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x}\, dx\\
&= \Gamma(\alpha) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha}.
\end{align}

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thank u very much..

Comment: can u explain 3. step pls?

Comment: Use the substitution $u = nx$.

Comment: @kaya_, did you understand?

Comment: exactly @kobe. thank you so much...